# Cpanel backup freezing in “fixing mail permission” state

Tags: backup, cpanel

My restoring action stops when it gets to "fixing mail permission" part of restoring Cpanle backup. Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to  Repair mailbox permissions as below, I hope it will help you if you are going to restore backup for already existing account.

WHM > Email > Repair mailbox permissions

Answer (score 0):

For a single cpanel account your can fix it by root SSH as

```
/scripts/mailperm username
```

username = cpanel User name